# BigQuery External Table - i can't create anymore - Make sure all fields are correct to continue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have already created external tables several times on BigQuery but for a few days it no longer wants to work and the error is too generic to understand.

[image]

It seems BigLake Option is blocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine with this alternative route https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Cloud-Hub/Unable-to-created-big-query-external-tables-using-GCS-datasets/m-p/445577 :

> We can be able to create the table via the command line using bq mk,
> [CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE in
> SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_external_table_statement)
> or via api:
> https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-cloud-storage#sql

In my case, the SQL Command line is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE {project_id}.{dataset_name}.{table_name}(
CODE STRING,
LOAD_AT TIMESTAMP ,
LOAD_TYPE STRING 
) OPTIONS (
    format = 'CSV',
    uris = ['gs://{my_bucket}/{folder}/{filename_suffix}__*.csv'],
    skip_leading_rows = 0,
    field_delimiter = "|");
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue was pointed out on [google support page](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Cloud-Hub/Unable-to-created-big-query-external-tables-using-GCS-datasets/m-p/458988#M1103). See my comment you can use DLL as a workaround.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE project_id.dataset_name.table_name (
  x STRING, 
  y INTEGER,
  z STRING,...
)
OPTIONS (
  format = GOOGLE_SHEETS,
  uris = ['https://url'],
  sheet_range='sheetRange',
  skip_leading_rows= 1
);
```